# How to properly call a function from a child process

Tags: c, child-process

I want to assign a random variable to every child. For example Child 1 gets a value of 0.515 and Child 2 gets a value of 0.911.

I tried the following code:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


double random()
{
    double x = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
    return x;
}


int main()
{
    int N = 10;
    pid_t pids[N];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        if ((pids[i] = fork()) < 0)
        {
            printf("Error using fork().\nExiting...\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
        else if (pids[i] == 0)
        {
            // get random value
            double result = random();
            printf("Child %d PID = %d. random() = %f.\n", i, getpid(), result);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
   
    while (N > 0)
    {
        wait(NULL);
        N--;
    }
   
    printf("Done.\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Which generates the following output:

```
Child 0 PID = 6531. random() = 0.840188.
Child 1 PID = 6532. random() = 0.840188.
Child 2 PID = 6533. random() = 0.840188.
Child 3 PID = 6534. random() = 0.840188.
Child 4 PID = 6535. random() = 0.840188.
Child 5 PID = 6536. random() = 0.840188.
Child 6 PID = 6537. random() = 0.840188.
Child 7 PID = 6538. random() = 0.840188.
Child 8 PID = 6539. random() = 0.840188.
Child 9 PID = 6540. random() = 0.840188.
Done.
```

As we can see every child gets the same random value, but I want them to all have different values.

Why do they all get the same number and how can I prevent this?

Comment: You should also call `srand(time(NULL));` (or with similar seed) in `main()` once before calling `rand()` or you will generate the same random sequence of numbers each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All child processes are starting with the same random seed and each calls `rand` once.  This is why they all have the same value.

You should call `rand` in the *parent* process before forking, that way you get different random numbers.  Then after the fork the child will have the value that was generated before the fork.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    // get random value
    double result = random();

    if ((pids[i] = fork()) < 0)
    {
        printf("Error using fork().\nExiting...\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if (pids[i] == 0)
    {
        printf("Child %d PID = %d. random() = %f.\n", i, getpid(), result);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: But it should be noted that if the children generate more random numbers, it will be obvious that they are all drawing from the same sequence.  If they need to generate independent sequences of pseudorandom numbers then they should each seed the RNG separately, with a distinct seed.  Possibly they could incorporate their PID into the seeds to ensure that they are all different.